# Query for List of user stories in rally that are not in the feature's Release

Tags: rally

I am trying to add a custom list on my dashboard that shows me a list of all user stories that are not part of the feature release

`(Release.Name != Feature.Release.Name)` isn't working

Comment: I think you haven’t provided enough information (or your code) for anybody to be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

WSAPI does not support expressions as the right hand side of a query, so you won't be able to use a custom list to find this data exactly.

But, if you know the name of the release you're looking at you can craft a query like this:

```
((Release.Name != "My Release") AND (Feature.Release.Name = "My Release"))
```

That would give you all stories with a different release than their parent feature.